# Shopify: catching exceptions of RestAPI calls from the ShopfyAPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am trying to catch an exception, when a certain id is not found, but the App still stops with the message:
ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound

The Code is the following:

```
begin
  ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.find(x.scriptid)
rescue => e
  if e.message == '404 Not Found'
  # handle 404 error
  else
    raise e
  end
end
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better practice here will be to rescue the exception you want, instead of `StandardError`

```
rescue ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound => e
  # handle 404 error
end
```

I can't say right away why your example doesn't work, but I guess that the message is not exactly `404 Not Found`

You can use regex in this case `e.message.match?(/404 Not Found/)`, but I'd prefer the approach above

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that the message is not exactly "404 Not found"

Comment: error objects also come with a code. And codes are often precise and offer you a way of dealing with problems too.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out as it's been pestering me too.
You can ask the Shopify API for a collection by passing in :all and a param of the ids. Then just raise an error manually if it returns an empty array.

```
begin
  @product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { ids: product_id })&.first || raise('Shopify product not found')
rescue => e
  puts e.message and return false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Oli's reply pointed me in the right direction, this one did the job for me:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.all(ids: member.shopify_id).first
```

then check for nil.